# Is it possible to define an angularjs constant inside a controller or config block?

Tags: angularjs, constants

I am trying to set up some app wide constants from a http endpoint. I don't want (or need ) to do it via the manual bootstrap way (ala [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data) ). Ideally I want to load the constants in after the user has signed in. So I assume I need to define the constants somewhere I can run some code (and use $http). But whenever I define a constant inside a controller or a config block, the constant gives an unknown provider error when I pass it into another module. As soon as I move the definition outside of the controller it works. So for example, if I have ...

```
  var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
      app.constant('test', 'test value');
```

then I can pass that into another module's controller like this:

```
  var app2 = angular.module('anotherModule',[testApp]);
  app2.controller('TestCtrl', ['test',
    function(test) {
        console.log(test)`
    }..
```

and this will output 'test value' as you would expect. But if the constant is defined inside a code block then it seems it doesn't register as a provider. So, for example:

```
  var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
      app.controller('firstCtrl',function(){
               app.constant('test', 'test value');
      }
```

If I run a page with that controller, the constant seems to register (in the sense that it is listed inside the _invokeQueue array on the testApp module) but the injector service doesn't have a provider for it and I get an unknown provider method for it on anotherModule.

I initially felt that a factory or service was overkill for what I was trying to do but maybe that is the way I should go. But I would also love to understand why a constant defined like this isn't injectable.

Comment: could declare it as an object...then extend the object

Comment: Module.constant is an angular concept that seems to be ideal for what I am trying to do but I just can't get it to be injectable if I define it inside a code block. I am hoping for some insight as to why that is and how I might programmatically define a constant that is injectable.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by defining a constant inside the controller? Does the constant depend on data from the controller?

Comment: Exactly. I basically wanted to share some static data out to various controllers in a way that I could initialise the data inside a post sign-in controller. A constant seemed the most logical structure. I ended up using a service that was called during a resolve as part of the routing - so it happened after the user signed in. The resolved object was injected into the controllers that needed that data. Quite a complicated solution but I couldn't get it work as a simple constant if I wanted to define it inside a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to load constants for HTML5 app:

1. add the following line into head section:
   < script src="service/constants.js">
2. create web api / wcf / java REST service method with signature "service/constants.js"
3. in that method return "window.constants = {...}".
4. replace "..." with actual key:value pairs read from database.

Comment: well, i'm trying to do it the angular way :) If I was to do it outside I'd probably use the manual bootstrap method linked in my question.